# what versions of firebase and google maps should i use?

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps

I am trying use firebase and Google maps in the same app but each time i sync the gradle files i get the following error: 
Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.1.

I have tried changing the play-services version but that has not solved the issue.
Below are the two gradle files

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myteam"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

root project `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'   
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio should tell you which versions are hopelessly outdated... which are commonly indicated with a yellowish background - and update suggestions are being shown, when hovering these with the mouse. telling how it works might be a better answer, than doing your job.

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0"   
    }
}
```

this should at least fix the one issue, while the other `build.gradle` has further outdated versions.

Comment: I have applied the changes you suggested and updated the build.gradle versions and it has got rid of the errors, thanks.